# Mousepointer always shows a scrollbar or black square

Tags: windows-10, mouse-cursor

Recently Windows 10 started to corrupt my mouse pointer and it ends up showing a horizontal scroll bar or a black square based on what I hover with it.

It becomes almost unusable because I need to use the upper left corner of the scroll bar when I select text anywhere which is quite confusing.

The issue is gone after a reboot, but I don't really want to reboot my PC every few hours.

Is there anything I can do to fix this?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you have Dark Mode ON?  Go to Control Panel, Mouse, Pointers Tab and look through the Scheme Drop down. Select a different theme. Try Windows Default.

Comment: @John Yes I had Dark Mode activated. I disabled it now. Switching the Scheme back and forth indeed fixed the issue! Thanks a lot. Want to add this as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have Dark Mode ON? Try Dark Mode On/Off

Go to Control Panel, Mouse, Pointers Tab and look through the Scheme Drop down. Select a different theme.

Try Windows Default, and other themes to help fix and suit you.

This should help you.